# detecting SQL queries from string in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've googled a lot about my question and even looked at many QAs here in SO, but couldn't find what I was looking for, anyway sorry if it is a duplicate question.
This is my scenario:
I have a string in C#, and it should be used as a SQL Server query. But this string can be anything, from a simple (select A from B) to a complicated SP (which may contain several commands). How can I explicitly DETECT each query in this string?
For instance let's say we have following string:

```
select columnA from tblB
delete tblD where ID='100'
insert into tblF (name) values ('test')
```

above text is clearly consisted of 3 different queries, each of which should be executed in its own specific way, i.e. the first one (select) needs ExecuteReader, and I should display a table of results, while the others require ExecuteNonQuery. So internally I should run 3 SQL queries, but the problem is how can I differentiate between these 3 queries? I cannot simply split string with '\n' as in SQL, a query can be written in multiple lines. What is the best/correct way of detecting different queries. (SQL Server Management Studio is a perfect example of what I'm looking for)
Should I use SQL Parsers? If so, what should I be looking for? I've seen a lot of parsers also, but am really confused as I don't know what should I exactly expect from them.

I did my best to describe the problem!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Something is seriously wrong with your application, if you are passing random SQL queries around like this.

Comment: Yes I know it may not be a great idea to let user do whatever he wants, but I'm almost certain that I'll always get SQL queries.

Comment: There is a reason you don't see anything on google, this is a terrible idea to let the user execute any query. Aside from that "minor" violation of programming 101, you're trying to write a sql parser which is not a trivial thing to do.

Comment: How did a user type these commands ?

Comment: Just let users split their commands themselves (like `GO` statement is used in sql tools).

Comment: As I told I know the whole idea is not logical, but anyway, I want to know how can it be done, and of course I'm not going ti reinvent the wheel, if there is a tool that can help me, I'm going to use it, but I don't know how to find that tool (if any at all!).

Comment: @Evk, good idea, it can be a solution but what if user doesn't consider inserting a "GO"? And even with GO, how can I split commands? the keyword "GO" can be used anywhere!

Comment: Well as I remember you cannot use sql statements on the same line with GO (so GO should be on separate line), and that is easy to parse.

Comment: What if one of the SQL statements is invalid? If you let users type arbitrary SQL commands there are bound to be typos and whatnot. Would it be OK for you to, say, have a form that will serve as a sort of query builder, with one combobox for the commands (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT etc), one for the `FROM` table, a CheckedListBox for column selection, etc.? This way you could allow for a great variety of commands whilst being able to validate each part, thren building a parametrized query from the parts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom` then this is quite straight forward (at least for the happy path)

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var sql = @"
SELECT columnA
FROM   tblB
WHERE  ColumnB = 1

DELETE tblD
WHERE  ID = '100'

INSERT INTO tblF
            (NAME)
VALUES      ('test'),
            ('foo'),
            ('bar') 
";

            var parser = new TSql100Parser(true); //Or TSql120Parser or whatever
            IList<ParseError> errors = new List<ParseError>();

            TSqlScript script = (TSqlScript)parser.Parse(new StringReader(sql), out errors);

            //TODO: Don't ignore errors
            foreach (var batch in script.Batches)
            {
                foreach (var st in batch.Statements)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(st.GetType().Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(sql.Substring(st.StartOffset, st.FragmentLength));
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: It was exactly what I was looking for! Your answer really worth >100000 thanks, well done Martin!

Comment: @Ali_dotNet splitting a batch up into statements and executing them individually won’t always work however. E.g if one of the statements is a `DECLARE @variable` that is referenced later. Management studio would just send the whole batch and subscribe to the info messages for the messages tab and loop through all resultsets returned for the grids.

Comment: And the OUTPUT clause means that Delete and insert statements can return resultsets.